# Android Studio - Schedule for Addition

Tags: svn, android-studio, project

I just checked out a working copy from **Subversion** in **Android Studio**.

When I wanted to open this project, I get asked the following: "**Do you want to schedule the following file for addition to Subversion?**"

Now does that mean, that if I indeed schedule the file for addition to Subversion, it automatically will be committed to subversion or something?

Or if I say "No", how can I manually add it back to "addition to Subversion"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you open the project, Android Studio notices some unversioned item in your project's [working copy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.working-copy) and prompts you to ask whether this item has to be added under version-control or not. In terms of svn.exe command-line client, Android Studio asks you to [`svn add`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.add.html) the item.

`svn add` command schedules files, directories, or symbolic links in your working copy for addition to [the repository](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.repository). The next time you will [`svn commit`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.commit.html) new revision, the addition will be committed to the repository.

Comment: Okay got that, thank you (would upvote, but I am still unable due to a too low rank) ...and thank you for editing my question!
hopefully I will start to understand the rules in here asap !

Answer (score 1):

you can go to settings, **ctrl+alt+s -> version control -> confirmation** : change the options of "**when files are created**".

also if it doesn't solved the issue you can right click on your project in intellij, go to **subvertion> edit properties**. check if there is a property named "**ignore" or "global-ignores**" with **"*"** value, remove **"*"** in these properties.

Answer (score 0):

Under `Local`, you have a section named `Unversioned Files`.

Select the files you want to schedule for adding in SVN, right click on them and select `Add to VCS`.

Then you should be able to commit your files as usual.